# Django Rest Framework - sending data / content to the frontend with an HTTP status code not working

Tags: angularjs, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

If you look at the DRF doucmentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/#status-codes, the "empty_code" view returns "content" (a python dictionary) along with the 404 status code.

This is my login view:

```
class login_view(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        user = authenticate(username=request.DATA["username"], password=request.DATA["password"])

        # return whatever you want on failure
        if not user or not user.is_active:
            content = {"credentials":"Username or password is incorrect. Please try again."}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        login(request, user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And this is AngularJS on the frontend:

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

self.loginUser = function() {
    $http.post("/CMS/custom-api-auth/login", self.loginuser)
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
     }); /*
    .then(fetchUsers); */
};
```

However, "content" does not get logged (the only thing I see in the console is the 400 error message).

It works for my other view:

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In the view above, serializer.data does get logged, however, "content" does not get logged. Any idea how I would be able to log "content" to the console?

Edit: I just logged and looked at the entire object being passed to the fontend if a user was not successfully logged in, and "data" seems to be empty:

```
Object {data: "", status: 400, config: Object, statusText: "BAD REQUEST"}
```

Comment: You are making a `POST` request to the server. Are you sending `csrf_token` with your request?

Comment: Can you try: 
import json//
content = json.dumps(content)//
I am not sure that works, but is the first thing i would try.

Comment: @xyres Good question. I'm actually fairly new to AngularJS and I copy-pasted code which I found online. I updated my JS in my original post. Can you have a look at it and verify that it is the correct way to send a csrf_token with the request?

Comment: @cdvv7788 Hm. Unfortunately  doing json.dumps(content) first does not work either. Data is still empty (data: "") when I log it.